# Why does changing the 0th index of the array change more than the 0th index?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
bool a[10];
a[0] = 1;
for (bool& e : a) cout << e;
```

Outputs `1000002000` instead of 1000000000, which I'd expect. Why is this?
If I make the array bigger the values get even more strange.

Comment: The rest of your array is uninitialized, try `bool a[10] = {};` instead.

Comment: You don't initialize the array, except `a[0]`. Uninitialized local variables (including all elements of arrays) really are uninitialized. Their values will be *indeterminate*, and in C++ using any kind of indeterminate value leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: how do you know that the value changed from the assignment? You should print the array elements also before the assignment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you notice that one of your `bool` values was 2?

That's one of many things that can happen when the behaviour of your program is *undefined*, which it is in your case since you are reading uninitialised non-`char` data.

```
bool a[10] = {};
```

is the fix.

Because the language is allowed to assume that a `bool` type can only store `false` or `true`, the `<<` overload on `ostream` is permitted to use code like

```
e + '0'
```

when outputting a `bool` type `e`. That of course wreaks havoc with incorrectly initialised data!

Answer (score 8):

Your bool array is not initialized so it's full of garbage. If you print the array before changing the first index (`[0]`), you will see it's not your assignment which changes the other parts.

For initializing I'd suggest this line

```
bool a[10] = {false};
```

Comment: Given a non-dynamic array, the initialization assignment is probably a better choice compared to Jains answer. Still, you should edit your addition into an actual answer, then you may soon have the points to write comments ;)

Answer (score 2):

You don't initialize the array.

Use `memset`, `fill_n` or `for` loop

```
memset(a, INIT_VALUE, sizeof(a)); // use only 0, -1 value, please.

fill_n(a, SIZE, INIT_VALUE); // or use this for save values.

for(bool &e : a) e = 0; // use loop init directly.
```